# of tornado and blocking code

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to move away from CherryPy for a web service that I am working on and one alternative that I am considering is Tornado. Now, most of my requests look on the backend something like:

- get POST data
- see if I have it in cache (database access)
- if not make multiple HTTP requests to some other web service which can take even a good few seconds depending on the number of requests

I keep hearing that one should not block the tornado main loop; I am wondering if all of the above code is executed in the `post()` method of a `RequestHandler`, does this mean that I am blocking the code ? And if so, what's the appropriate approach to use tornado with the above requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado comes shipped with an asynchronous (actually [two](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/simple_httpclient.py) iirc) http client ([AsyncHTTPClient](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpclient.py)). Use that one if you need to do additional http requests.

The database lookup should also be done using an asynchronous client in order to not block the tornado ioloop/mainloop. I know there are a couple of tornado tailor made database clients (e.g [redis](http://github.com/kmerenkov/brukva), [mongodb](https://github.com/bitly/asyncmongo)) out there. The mysql lib is included in the tornado distribution.